# How to mock a property using NUnit?

Tags: c#, .net, nunit, mocking

How do I mock a property using NUnit?

---

**NOTE**: I found [this peripheral mocking answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591174/how-to-mock-the-property-which-returns-the-list-object-in-rhino-mock/594933#594933) to be extremely useful and repurposed it as a distinct question and answer entry here for others to find.

Other answers welcome too.

> **NUnit-Discuss Note:**
>   *NUnit Mocks was created over a weekend
>   as a toy mock implementation [...] I'm beginning to think that was a mistake, because you are far 
>   from the first person to become reliant on it.*
>   -- http://groups.google.com/group/nunit-discuss/msg/55f5e59094e536dc
>   (Charlie Pool on NUnit Mocks)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To mock the *Names* property in the following example...

```
Interface IView {    
    List<string> Names {get; set;} 
}

public class Presenter {    
    public List<string> GetNames(IView view)    {
       return view.Names;    
    } 
}
```

### NUnit Mock Solution for a Property

```
using NUnit.Mocks;
```

In NUnit a *PropertyName* can be mocked with **get_PropertyName** to mock the get accessor and **set_PropertyName** to mock the set accessor, using the mock library's **Expect*(..)** methods like so:

```
List names = new List {"Test", "Test1"};
DynamicMock mockView = new DynamicMock(typeof(IView));

mockView.ExpectAndReturn("get_Names", names);

IView view = (IView)mockView.MockInstance;
Assert.AreEqual(names, presenter.GetNames(view));
```

Therefore, in our specific code sample at the top,  the *.Names* property is mocked as either **get_Names** or **set_Names**.

---

### Etc.

[This blog post](http://www.vergentsoftware.com/blogs/ckinsman/usingNUnitMocksDynamicMockWithAPropertyInC.aspx) provides additional insight considering NUnit seemingly provides mock methods to only target methods:

> I started thinking about it and
>   realized that Property getters and
>   setters are just treated as speciallly
>   named methods under the covers

Comment: I've fleshed out John K's example so it actually compiles under .NET 2.0 - note that wherever you use mock.Expect() or mock.ExpectAndReturn() you should always follow it up with mock.Verify()...

Comment: Stupid short-text editor... `using System.Collections.Generic;
using NUnit.Framework;
using NUnit.Mocks;

namespace StackExchange5331412
{
 public interface IView
 {
  List<string> Names { get; set; }
 }

 public class Presenter
 {
  public List<string> GetNames(IView view)
  {
   return view.Names;
  }
 }`

Comment: ` [TestFixture]
 public class TestIView
 {
  [Test]
  public void TestNames()
  {
   List<string> names = new List<string>();
   names.AddRange(new string[] { "Test", "Test1" });

   DynamicMock mockView = new DynamicMock(typeof(IView));
   mockView.ExpectAndReturn("get_Names", names);
   //mockView.Expect("set_Names", names);

   IView view = (IView)mockView.MockInstance;
   Presenter presenter = new Presenter();
   Assert.AreEqual(names, presenter.GetNames(view));

   mockView.Verify();
  }
 }
}`

Comment: Link in answer is giving *"This site can’t be reached"*.